# I couldn't change this Firebase v8 code to v9

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I want to change this below **Firebase V8** code to **Firebase V9** :

I tried many ways but it shows error

Please change this code to version 9

see full code : https://github.com/SimCoderYoutube/InstagramClone/blob/master/frontend/components/main/Save.js

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
require("firebase/firestore")
require("firebase/firebase-storage")

const uploadImage = async () => {
        const uri = props.route.params.image;
        const childPath = `post/${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}/${Math.random().toString(36)}`;
        console.log(childPath);

        const response = await fetch(uri);
        const blob = await response.blob();

        const task = firebase.storage()
        .ref()
        .child(childPath)
        .put(blob);

        const taskProgress = snapshot => {
            console.log(`transferred: ${snapshot.bytesTransferred}`)
        }

        const taskCompleted = () => {
            task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((snapshot) => {
                savePostData(snapshot);
                console.log(snapshot)
            })
        }

        const taskError = snapshot => {
            console.log(snapshot)
        }

        task.on("state_changed", taskProgress, taskError, taskCompleted);
    }
```

Node modules are installed correctly.
But it shows Error:

```
./node_modules/firebase/firebase-storage.js:1
Module not found: Can't resolve 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.5.0/firebase-app.js'
> 1 | import { getApp, _getProvider, _registerComponent, registerVersion, SDK_VERSION } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.5.0/firebase-app.js';
  2 |
  3 | /**
  4 |  * @license
```

Comment: What error does it show? What was your attempt?

Comment: ./node_modules/firebase/firebase-storage.js:1
Module not found: Can't resolve 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.5.0/firebase-app.js'
> 1 | import { getApp, _getProvider, _registerComponent, registerVersion, SDK_VERSION } from 'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.5.0/firebase-app.js';
  2 |
  3 | /**
  4 |  * @license

Comment: Try to import and not require `firebase/firestore` and `firebase/firebase-storage`

Comment: i tried it but it Not working